# Query a database and output result to build IN statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a query in C# which I'm executing off of my server.  It returns one column, but I'd like to take the results of the column and generate them into an IN statement to pass through to another query off of a different server.

Here's the code, I just don't know how to write the logic to output each row:

```
            System.Data.DataTable dtCups = new System.Data.DataTable();
            var dataSet = new DataSet();

            string connString = "Data Source=My Server;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;";

            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            Conn.Open();
            
            String qryCups = "select cups from table"; //returns 300 rows

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(qryCups, Conn);
            adapter.Fill(dtCups);
            Conn.Close();
 
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtCups.Rows)
            {
                string cups = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                DataRow[] MatchRecs = dtCups.Select("cups='" + dr.ItemArray[0] + "'");

            }
```

Just not sure what to do as it is looping through each record but not appending the prior cup value to the next value, like 'cup1','cup2', etc.

Thanks in advance.

Code for the next sql statement would be

```
String qryFinal = "select cups from table_B where cups in '" + [the output of the data above] + "'";
```

And I would insert that result into a final table or drop to Excel (which I know how to do);

Comment: Please add the code that should use these values in the IN statement for the following query.

Comment: ahh yes, SQL Injection

Comment: Thanks Steve, i added it.  It's basically just an in statement off of another select, but the first query I need to store in a variable so I can pass it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read your table and row by row create two lists. The first one will contain parameter names, the second one the parameters itself with the values extracted by your datatable.
At loop exit you build an query text joining together the parameter names inside the IN statement and then pass the parameters to the SqlCommand itself.

```
List<string> pNames = new List<string>();
List<SqlParameter> prms = new List<SqlParameter>();
for (int x = 0; x < dtCups.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    // Create the parameters names list @0, @1, @2 etc..
    pNames.Add($"@{x}");

    // Create the parameters, note that I assume a string type parameter with a length of 255 characters max. Adjust if assumption is wrong
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter($"@{x}", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
    p.Value = dtCups.Rows[x][0].ToString();
    prms.Add(p);
}

.....

// Create the final sql command text from the parameters names
string qryFinal = "select cups from table_B where cups in(" + 
                  string.Join(",", pNames) + ")";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qryFinal, connection);

// Add the parameter list to the command collection and then execute
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 

// Or DataAdapter.Fill table
DataTable aTable = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da1.Fille(aTable);
```